# How to stop removing one class when another class selected in Tinymce

Tags: tinymce

```
<span class="token">This is a string.</span>
```

---

If I select another class like 'string', the old class remove automatically. solution please. Thank you

Comment: How are you applying the class?  Perhaps you can make a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows exactly how you have TinyMCE setup?

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed description of what you are doing, and as suggested above provide a fiddle or working example?  Without knowing how you are trying to add a class, it's very difficult to answer this questions. Also, please provide the code you are using to initialize TinyMCE as that might be very helpful.